# Locked out from Win 11 by BitLocker after trying Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bitlocker, windows-11

I recently got a HP ENVY x360 15.
It came with Windows 11 pre installed.
I shrank the the main partition on the SSD, using Windows built in tools, to allow space for a later installation of Linux. And all worked well.

I created a bootable USB-stick using Rufus.
Then changed the Boot order in BIOS.
And loaded Ubuntu 21.10 (without installing) just to test some basic functions.

When restarting the computer I'm prompted for a BitLocker recovery key.

I have not enabled BitLocker i Windows and I have no BitLocker key.
I have looked at my Microsoft account and there's no information about BitLocker.

I have tried changing the UEFI Bott Order back to "OS Boot Manager", to no effect.
I'm still locked out from Windows.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Without the recovery key there isn’t a solution to your problem that doesn’t involve a clean install of Windows. BitLocker is impossible to automatically activate. Your being asked for the recovery key due to the configuration changes you made. In order to activate BitLocker you are required to go through a confirmation process that involves backing up the recovery key

Comment: @ramhound, there are lots of reports of Windows 11 automatically encryting with bitlocker and not mentioning it or giving you the option to backup the key.  See for example : https://www.elevenforum.com/t/windows-11-encrypted-my-drive-automatically.1244/ According to that thread it happens on clean install of Win 11 too if your hardware supports it.

Comment: @Ramhound. If what you're saying is correct - there are only one logical explanation: BitLocker is not activated on my computer. My problems must then be that Windows, for some reason, believes that BitLocker is active.

Comment: You should have used Virtual Machines instead of dual boot. Experimenting with Dual Boot can be a disaster.

Comment: @Populus_22 - The only reason you would be prompted for a BitLocker recovery key is BitLocker protection was actually enabled.

Comment: @John, have had little problem using dual-boot in Windows 10 and Linux. Windows 11, itself, is still a work in progress.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Windows 11 is just Windows 10 with some major UI work

Comment: @Ramhound, in theory, Windows 11 *should* have been a simple adaptation of Windows 10. From what I've seen on the web, however, MS has removed features and added some bugs, e.g., https://www.minitool.com/backup-tips/windows-11-bugs-errors-issues-problems.html , https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-microsoft-needs-to-fix/, https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/12/26/microsoft-confirms-another-windows-11-issue-promises-fix-in-a-future-release/ . Admittedly, this is not from my own usage, but from reading.

Comment: @Greenmarty - Device Encryption is often mistaken for BitLocker being enabled. 2 year old comment isn’t worth pinging a user for